# Positioned and optional group

Tags: python, regex

My example data set:

```
Loaded: mismatch (No such file or directory)
Loaded: not-found ()
Loaded: error (Reason:No such file or directory)
Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
Loaded: mystery
```

My regex test (read line by line):

```
re.findall("[Loaded: ](\S*) \([Reason: ]?(.*)\)", line)
```

I get respectively:

```
[('mismatch', 'No such file or directory')]
[('not-found', '')]
[('error', 'eason:No such file or directory')]
[('error', 'eason: No such file or directory')]
```

First and second list are ok.

But the third and fourth are not and it lacks the fifth.

How to fix that?

Comment: The second and fifth don't have `Reason` which is a mandatory part of your regex.

Comment: `Reason` is not a mandatory part in the regex. it's surrounded by `[]`. therefore, it's interpreted as charset. so is `loaded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need, but it matches all
your test strings properly.

Group 1 is the loaded message, Group 2 is the reason.

```
 # Loaded:\s+(\S+)(?:\s+\((?:Reason:\s*)?([^)]*)\))?     

 Loaded: \s+ 
 ( \S+ )                  # (1)
 (?:
      \s+ 
      \( 
      (?: Reason: \s* )?
      ( [^)]* )                # (2)
      \) 
 )?
```

Comment: Just perfect:) I will try to analyze it to understand a little better regex. Big thank you to you sin. Thank you to alfasin and HuStmpHrrr for trying.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall(r"Loaded:\s*(\S*)\s*(?:\((?:Reason:\s*)?(.*)\))?", line)
```

try this one instead.

Comment: With this, 1, 2 and 4 are ok. But in 3 I get "Reason:" wich is too. And not get 5.